# KEDA autoscaling RabbitMq based on message processing

Tags: spring, kubernetes, rabbitmq, keda

I have an spring boot app that consume from RabbitMq I deployed this app and make autoscale based on the queueLength , I want to make to scale down more effecinet by not scaling down the pod if there is an message is processing on that pod how can I achieve this please and need i to publish a long message to rabbitMq to simulate this ? thnaks in advance for any kind of help .

Comment: There is no mechanism for this. You need to make sure that the message is acknowledged only at the end of the operator. That way it can get picked up again if the spring boot app dies due to scaling.